# Laravel - Validation save selected option

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have a form which has some validation. When one of these errors occurs the value of an input field will be saved be using `{{ old('name') }}` in the value field of an input. But this is only for regular text input fields.

My problem.

How can I save the selected value of a select box using the same method? So that if the user comes across an error, Their selected option will still be selected?

The code where the selected

```
<select name="period_id" id="" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('period_id') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}">
   <option value="">Choose a period...</option>
     @foreach($plans as $plan)
     <option value="{{ $plan->id }}">
        {{ $plan->name }}
     </option>
     @endforeach
</select>

@if($errors->has('period_id'))
 <p style="color: red;"> {{ $errors->first('period_id') }}</p>
@endif
```

**EDIT**

```
array:9 [▼
  "_token" => "flBWl0qRV7GnMYL0D90G"
  "name" => "Product name"
  "description" => "Descriptiobn"
  "price" => "1,000"
  "productable_type" => "App\Plan"
  "period_id" => "2"
  "periodically_price" => "25"
  "composer_package" => "asdasdsasasad"
  "thumbnail" => UploadedFile {#654 ▶}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check each of the options and add the `selected` attribute to the old one.

`<option value="{{ $plan->id }}" {{ $plan->id === old('planid') ? 'selected' : '' }}>`

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work for me. It doesn't give me any errors so I cant tell what it returns.

Comment: can you show us a `dd($request->all())` of a succesfully submitted form? (this is to check that 1) the value is sent to the server 2) the exact name of the field)

Comment: I changed old('plan_id') to old('period_id') because that's how the field is called but it still doesn't work

Comment: 1) can you inspect the html to check if the attribute gets added to it 2) change `===` to `==` and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try it via the Form helper of `Laravel`

`{!! Form::select("input_name", $optionForSelect, old('input_name', isset($valueInput) ? $valueInput : ''), ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'input_name']) !!}`